# Обособленное приложение, отнесенное к личному местоимению

Tags: обособление

Считается, что обособленное приложение, отнесенное к личному местоимению, является определением, но вот почему?

Личное местоимение относится к разряду местоименных существительных и (как и все местоимения) УКАЗЫВАЕТ на лицо или предмет, не называя его.

В этом случае обособленное приложение, отнесенное к личному местоимению, НЕ ОПРЕДЕЛЯЕТ предмет, а НАЗЫВАЕТ, раскрывает его содержание. Ведь недаром личное местоимение не образует необособленное словосочетание с приложением. И вопрос "КАКОЙ" по отношению к обособленному приложению звучит неестественно.

Поэтому у школьников и возникает вопрос, как подчеркивать обособленное приложение в таком предложении: "Ему ли, карлику, тягаться с исполином?" Формально подчеркивается как определение, но кажется, что это дополнение: Кому именно? - Карлику.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

"Карлик" из вопроса убирается, а то он все запутал. Случайно попал сюда, по ошибке. Карлик - это человек маленького роста, приложение со значением признака. Поэтому "карлик" решительно изгоняется.

Заменим его "рябиной": "Как же  мне, рябине, к дубу перебраться". И недавний похожий пример, признанный приложением и подчеркнутый волнистой чертой: Сколько их, монументов славы...". Так здесь приложение или уточняющее дополнение? И как этот  обособленный член подчеркивать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Видимо, оправдание такой условности можно поискать в том, что местоимение относится к конкретному лицу (или предмету) а приложение ссылается на широкий класс "(**такому**) карлику" (**какому ему?**), на принадлежность обозначенного местоимением к людям низкорослым и потому неконкурентоспособным в этой ситуации. Ещё сложнее в случае, когда приложение выражено именем собственным:

Ему ли, Сеньке, пялить шапку Мономаха?

Если в качестве "адвоката дьявола" отстаивать "Сеньку" как определение (а не уточнение, что речь в предложении идёт о возможностях лично Семёна), можно сказать, что вопрос здесь "какому ему?", а "Сеньке" рассматривать как эквивалент выражения "такому как Сенька (которого все знают и с качествами которого всё ясно)". При этом акцент остаётся на местоимении, указывающем на конкретного человека, а Сенька оказывается чем-то вроде "прилагательного" (он же Сенька, Вася Пупкин - вот какой "он").

Comment: Александр, имена имена, фамилии, отчества, прозвища людей не являются приложением. Следовательно, в этом предложении Сеньке является уточнением. Имена, прозвище людей могут выступать в качестве приложения,если поясняют либо уточняет-нарицательное существительное (перед таким приложением можно без изменения смысла вставить слова а именно, то есть, а зовут его):
  **>Дочь Дарьи Михайловны, Наталья Алексеевна, с первого взгляда могла не понравиться (Т.); 
 >Отец мой, Клим Торсуев, известный мыловар, был человек тяжёлого характера (Ж. Г.);**

Comment: Спасибо за ответы, но вообще-то меня интересует вопрос в целом по теме, а не по частным предложениям. Вот сравним два варианта: (1) А он, мятежный, просит бури (обособленное определение, вопрос КАКОЙ ОН). (2) А он, парус, просит бури (обособленное приложение, КТО ОН). Во втором случае не признак предмета называется, а сам предмет. Тогда какое же это определение?

Comment: Вера, вопрос действительно интересный. Ответ найти на него найти сложно. Возможно, ответ стоить искать в теоретических грамматиках. В практические грамматики вряд ли дадут ответ на этот вопрос.

Comment: Серж, "Сенька" (в отличие от Натальи Алексеевны и Клима), не является уточнением, о ком именно идёт речь - соответственно, эти примеры нельзя противопоставить предложенной трактовке "Сеньки". Эти примеры отличаются и от такого (в котором из контекста уже известно, что местоимение относится к Моське):

Ей ли, Моське, лаять на Слона?

(из этого следует, что она маловата для произведения испуга у слона; разумеется, в другом контексте это может быть уточнением)

Comment: Да, Серж, Вы мне указали правильный путь. В Грамматике-80 сказано, что обособленные приложения выполняют ТРИ ФУНКЦИИ: 1) Признаковое приложение с определительным значением (Два почтенных мужа, честь и украшение Миргорода, поссорились между собой). 2) Обстоятельственное значение (Суровый славянин, я слез не проливал). 3) Конкретизирующее значение (А его, Ивана Игнатьевича, прошу быть моим секундантом).

Comment: Таким образом, обособленное приложение, отнесенное к местоимению, определительного значения НЕ ИМЕЕТ, но может иметь два других значения. Но, конечно, указаний по школьному грамматическому разбору там не дается, и вопрос остается открытым и решенным условно.

Comment: Александр,Натальи Алексеевны и Клима -уточняющие приложения.Сенька же не является уточняющим приложением. Это просто уточнение. Имена людей не выступают в качестве приложений.

Comment: Вера,учитывая,что приложения - род разновидность определения,то и подчеркивать надо как определение.

Comment: А вопрос как задавать?  Или вообще не задавать? Например: Им,моим друзьям, ничего неизвестно. Моим друзьям - это каким? или кому именно?

Answer (score 2):

```
 "Ему ли, карлику, тягаться с исполином?" Формально подчеркивается как определение, но кажется, что это дополнение: Кому именно? - Карлику.
```

"Карлику" не может быть дополнением **по определению** , 
потому что дополнение - это второстепенный член предложения, указывающий на предмет, на который направлено действие или который является результатом действия. Дополнения выражают объектные отношения и отвечают на вопросы косвенных падежей. Здесь нет объектных отношений.

Определение — это второстепенный член предложения, который обозначает признак предмета, его качество, свойство и отвечает на вопросы: какой? чей? который? Определение подчинено существительному, называющему характеризуемый предмет или явление.

Приложение — это определение, выраженное именем существительным. Определяя предмет, приложение дает ему другое название. Приложения могут иметь самые разные значения.

1. Классификационный разряд,к которому принадлежит предмет (лицо): род занятий, профессия, специальность, должность, социальная и национальная принадлежность, возраст, родство и т. д.
2. Свойства и качества предмета, его характеристика    Петух-драчун, машина-малютка, завод-гигант, чародейка-зима
3. Обозначение названия предмета, а также географического наименования (кроме собственных имен лиц)

Ему, карлику,.. Ему какому по своим свойствам? карлику, то есть очень маленькому. Приложение "карлик "выполнило свою роль определения - ОПРЕДЕЛИЛО, дало характеристику лицу, дало ему второе имя(название). Здесь имеет ещё и добавочное причинное значение- потому ему и нельзя тягаться с исполином, что он карлик.

А ученикам надо почаще напоминать, что приложение - второе название предмета, которое даёт ему характеристику. Правда, это определение не академическое, а лично моё, но вполне соответствует академической науке.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ, я прокомментирую его по возможности.

Comment: Людмила, полностью с вами согласен!

Comment: В грамматике существует тема обособленных пояснительных ВТОРОСТЕПЕННЫХ членов, ОПРЕДЕЛЕНИЙ И ОБСТОЯТЕЛЬСТВ, которые раскрывают содержание соответствующих местоименных слов: "Там, за седыми горами, тёмный нахмурился лес. Чичиков немного озадачился таким, отчасти резким, определением". В этих случаях мы имеем два определения или два обстоятельства, отвечающих на один и тот же вопрос.

Comment: Приложения могут выполнять ДВЕ РАЗЛИЧНЫЕ ФУНКЦИИ: (1) обозначать признак предмета (Кто, силач, возьмёт в охапку холм Кремля-богатыря? Я пришла сюда, бездельница, всё равно мне, где скучать! ) и (2) называть предмет другими словами (Саша, он, мой товарищ, его брат, этот человек и т.д.).

Comment: Именно в этой второй функции обособленные приложения, отнесенные к личному местоимению, СХОДНЫ С ОБОСОБЛЕННЫМИ ПОЯСНИТЕЛЬНЫМИ ОБСТОЯТЕЛЬСТВАМИ И ОПРЕДЕЛЕНИЯМИ и в принципе могут считаться ПОЯСНИТЕЛЬНЫМИ ДОПОЛНЕНИЯМИ ИЛИ ПОДЛЕЖАЩИМИ (что видно и по вопросам):  Как же мне, рябине, к дубу перебраться? (Кому? – Мне. Кому именно? – Рябине).А я думала: вот он, мой сюжет.

Comment: Кто ж спорит, что "мне, рябине,"-уточнение? "Рябина" только называет предмет, и это прямое значение предмета. А вот "Ему ли, карлику, тягаться с исполином" -карлик и исполин- переносный смысл, характеристика-один маленький, другой большой. Со школьниками-то понятно, они могут что угодно перепутать, но что Вы утверждаете, что" "карлик"  НЕ ОПРЕДЕЛЯЕТ предмет, а НАЗЫВАЕТ, раскрывает его содержание", меня очень удивляет. Карлик - карликового роста, карликовый, исполин-огромного роста - не просто определение, но ещё и эпитет, как красавица цыганка-красивая цыганка. Неужели это кому-то непонятно?

Comment: Это как раз не "Формально подчеркивается как определение", как Вы утверждаете, а по сути своей, по смыслу, а вот похоже оно на дополнение формально, но нужно вдумываться в текст, чему я своих учеников всю жизнь и учила, они это отличают,а вот сама на старости лет иногда не вдумываюсь, пробежала глазами, ляпнула - а там совсем другое, вдумаешься потом - видишь ошибку, но я на своих ошибках никогда не настаиваю.В моём возрасте и состоянии это вполне обычно. И Вам того желаю.

Answer (score 1):

Вера, вот что мне удалось найти. Думаю, вам поможет разобраться. Здесь говорится вот что: '***'Приложение -это в некотором смысле дополнение к существительному, которое даёт <<поясняющий смысл>>''.*** Приложение выполняет роль пояснения существительного. Также существует второе определение : Приложение это некоторый вид определения. [Приложение в русском языке](http://yandex.ru/clck/jsredir?from=yandex.ru%3Bsearch%2F%3Bweb%3B%3B&text=&etext=662.2aeXoYSRaJyWEUzlha8abH_9b3o3so1Sbg34lsR4Fme7OLC4BtBU5925EkjrAE-Uz1m7SboMe2PegjdIhpZ63mvdgKLle0JjHDck4lYZFXo.b27a6ccce41ce0c3b709dae4b01fa803899b452a&uuid=&state=PEtFfuTeVD5kpHnK9lio9XRXFZbT4Ua2FWo80joDQ0PY982vMS6LPA&data=UlNrNmk5WktYejR0eWJFYk1LdmtxcGxZZnhMVmluYjhFUGVRYWdNZmtKY3JlY0VQcG9hSzBxQmVUOFFxdnRzYng1OWVBRzJZRU5tN2NxeXh3WHkzNDUyZ1BGY0NjVnBIT1k0NXdUQlRSaENxZFBxMm9tNXFEdFAxY3U1ZG5MVHBqOEZ1MDk2VzFuMkkxOEtfcTJ5aFBB&b64e=2&sign=9aa54cfda1ed0ffb69ad910bb598e999&keyno=0&cst=AiuY0DBWFJ7IXge4WdYJQYtNprRPFzufqudLJZKAOLwoDTdQIxazSeWiChev90bYFecXuYsoEIL6KFSZzhjszPArdaAiQTYnsV5mdxdoebi2q3lLjf7DkZsFSVo-F9RPxptd9i-C4Dkfv2SuVibo6ojOJSKMRq16uAaTgCYR--C1vaOsIbFTBmP1jhQD3rwxE2lKER7QeAddV5rOZPc997jzOu_evHfD&ref=cM777e4sMOAycdZhdUbYHpMQ80108_UCHgI4h6Y0hbtoes4Cfdh8gMTSPTp66QEHcN46HXs91oKQMJTSI-_d4DJR6KjaEBGiEiXknaqfjKkoU1s6XZyEtJRP_UaXq0Ppx-tAsilSVVYZMNu5_KwurJqMltwzNw2dJQsPx1tUz4rCqVdiT9gQw2mP5DBXWF7HqDyKIu_1B3iYdAWWDs7IeOq5zgOcRiw07yBX2ajvK00hDSQ1lKadkQlRiHfNghvKiKzUgyZyG8sTmOXbwqhFm9o9n4zL4i1BNn5_t0COMsgEJnbbiq2iCorudF3JvH1YAWpdkIKTMplSYXs_vDeOi8NbdVR5-B5HJ_joZ32pWRy5mZgCqh13BQIEU_IOvYBP_vhWZhSIr5MBMbHdNIee2kR2CaQAqLHi8AZkf7gH9YZj8pijRRbkM4uewdot7asdt8QfH47A3j6vZUks31aqKsSdxrDlnfvNV-ms07XctHjCWeeVSeAbQ9sWrEpvgZzf8TLWDuzOPU83eLt7fH8PsdYJTV8AEajs3ra9zct4saoPaT6MFVyzZ0OKZctfYq2G8ERgOgLOw32L21HGLm2-Oq0ZBNZlll0znYMnJN_BgTahKNursZ56zx_7A7nnsFt5Pd86CwtYQCC2jfRRbaGEgTd6onSl-lGmghKZMQt2uxZjIHpMbKTqSzN5hBJQ3-0NOWoxg8ua4ZO1to3nHHdaxhvvD8JvM6Tv3oVYsfvdINYnLQRH8FHo5YB_5JguEck8gtCEmKvCOP8a74v7H6ReVXHzEaMqLhfIYZ3CNLXGeW5PBJcs2MpnPxFRePeLH4lDfJRSIakY_Uaz2nmGFJm_sqQU-gDsLz3CHyj7W7Grrrt896OvkFpV5dp9YoLLEHYTc0p4p1KpYopsurUKjznVa5udCrzZ0B84f8M13KuZzjkmGQELcFjVuBcIKfR4mg_0mFJg0mzTouCuqKPhDIK19WkL46eTrqgSz_ia2xlmpIKaYCezTNCZWrsF7gKMqlwCntuvMMOH0oClWuvao_TSp3Nvdl93_vD74423qUYZHtaG1TGMK6g5RWjD_fwBIQEpIP9ZEhk4SUKfRUGfj34sGLwrSV0pTH10tXnt5azjzdHXCMUBG1j3QjdOIXldwUjoHH4SALMxs_PGRz8vjOQN9fxS89MIZjPZqkdeEIaxfDCBrbY80s1DH_AmkpQXrZNIFolrDB0nvoQOLNJaEvOmMKU3rIHLKzApvWginhwlmqegGQWaSV2ui7XOsW1PnRFjAHPz6QmUb6w9glsjwW-OZRfCtGcfTKQV0pbVSNSlaQ8AjcCQH5ZsFdQizqdNj4ziY14EQLeohs3TrJRxmDv1kqimNT3fiflnWWCg6CVrYHU4cOkNtxVs4rv0EfAQ--_Ks-BLKmSWmc9nEdqOQQFO0luplWY_VhRoNpyITXGTKSWMr6LHDNbFKDcvahrSZBI6KQe0_ACq5rFn4J9oZHtLWvtLplfzfR05pA3jP4gsVwSMpSnwLSgWebE5W5va29EpK41O6c1MQj9E4BndnrxGAYHzmrgBJcCeCD1LPRf_Lm6_E1zMERpNprecdr8EuDpBFkW9O_ZcRb6CjU5N5eZFqwLg2dlNehFvcndhTw5uBvtnMyYE23o0RXY5IBD9xVsOMiag1SygqeZCv8O0FW2mNBwDQjQzd_aLbvJfreHQq490F3rcr0C1h9VeNjmaILAwu9HeGcsO5gw&l10n=ru&cts=1429384359776&mc=4.583610625265139)

Comment: Серж, Вы смеётесь? Думаете, Вера-София не разбирается в приложениях? Она Вам целую лекцию сейчас прочитает (с сайта)

Comment: Серж, большое спасибо за информацию. И еще. Уважаемые друзья и коллеги, я очень ценю дружественную атмосферу этого сайта. Также я очень ценю возможность повысить свой  уровень знаний при обсуждении спорных вопросов, различных "белых пятен" в орфографии. Нигде не получишь такой школы. Но вот что меня огорчает, так это необоснованные отступления от темы,от сути вопросов, упоминание личных качеств участников (обычно негативных). Вот я вам расскажу историю.

Comment: Как-то на другом форуме я высказала очень спорную идею, на что мне ответили: "Какой бред!" Немного поговорив с участником, я написала: "Извините, но беседа в Вами не доставляет мне удовольствия. Предполагаю, что Вы не из тех людей, которые стремятся истину найти".
Этот комментарий был удален в связи с жалобой "обиженного", также были начислены штрафные очки за "отступление от темы".

Comment: Тогда я пожаловалась модератору: "А бредом можно ответ называть?"  Удивительно, но за это мне дали премию, обозначенную как "страж порядка". У нас здесь, конечно, лучше, здесь как-то всё по-домашнему. Но досадные моменты всё-таки встречаются.

Comment: Людмила, я сомневаюсь в знаниях Веры. Ее интересовало,может ли быть приложение дополнением? Вот и нашел я то, что искала она!

Comment: Кстати, я так и думал, что Вера - София! Но не был уверен!